# Magento2 add new cloumn and mass action in newsletter admin grid

Tags: magento2, newsletter

How we can add "new column" and "new action" in newsletter in magento2 ***admin  grid as Newsleter doesn't have ui_component .***

So anybody can please help me as i can see newsletter grid  is coming from `newsletter_subscriber_block.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create following xml file for add column:

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/newsletter_subscriber_block.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Column</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">subscriber_confirm_code</argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-email</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">ccol-email</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.massaction">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="unsubscribeTEST" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribe TEST</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massUnsubscribe</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here **index** should be table column name.

```
<argument name="index" xsi:type="string">subscriber_confirm_code</argument>
```

Comment: How we can add New mass action in same as i have try to do in this way ?

<referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.massaction">
<block class= "Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">unique_name</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do massaction</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="atwix_testattribute/order/domassaction"/>
    </item>
</argument>
</block>
 </referenceBlock>

Comment: yes, check updated answer.

Comment: I have added the same code as you have suggested above for mass action..........
<item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massUnsubscribe</item>..
as..
<item name="url" xsi:type="string">vendorname_modulename/foldername/massTets</item>
"massTest" is my new action............I have added the controller file in controller Vendorname\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Foldername\MassTest extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Subscriber...........
every time page goes to 404.............In browser url comes correct.........so can you please let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: any updates on above comment "I have added............................."

Comment: show your routes.xml. vendorname_modulename/foldername/massTets should be 'frontName/[foldername]/massTets'.

Answer (score 0):

You can column from that file "newsletter_subscriber_block.xm" you can see code like for add column:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="firstname">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer First Name</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">firstname</argument>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="string">----</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-first-name</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-first-name</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment
but what will be the file path will it be like this 
app\code\Vendorname\Modulename\view\adminhtml\layout\newsletter_subscriber_block.xml ?

do we need to override or simply copy the file from vendor\magento\module-newsletter\view\adminhtml\layout\newsletter_subscriber.xml and copy in app\code\Vendorname\Modulename\view\adminhtml\layout\newsletter_subscriber_block.xml ? and added the new column in my file

Comment: For override xml file please check :https://codedump.io/share/eHbvu0qLWInj/1/in-magento-2-how-to-override-phtml-or-layout-core-files